# JFrog Jenkins Artifactory Plug-in. Problem build gradle with git submodules

Tags: artifactory

JFrog Jenkins Artifactory Plug-in. Problem build gradle with git submodules.

Hello!

I had a problem using the plugin to work with gradle.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-GradleBuildswithArtifactory.1

If I use a simple git repository, then there is no problem.

```
node(nodeName) {

  def rtGradle = Artifactory.newGradleBuild()
  def buildInfo

  stage('checkout') {
    checkout([$class                           : 'GitSCM',
              branches                         : [[name: gitBranch]],
              doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
              extensions                       : [],
              submoduleCfg                     : [],
              userRemoteConfigs                : [[credentialsId: gitCredentials, url: gitBORepo]]])
  }

  stage('wiki_gradle') {
    rtGradle.tool = "gradle2.5"
    def gradleTask = 'cleanComplete'

    buildInfo = rtGradle.run rootDir: 'delivery', buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: gradleTask
  }
}
```

However, if you use the same code with minor changes, when working with the repository submodule, an error occurs.

```
node(nodeName) {

  def rtGradle = Artifactory.newGradleBuild()
  def buildInfo

  stage('checkout') {
    checkout([$class                           : 'GitSCM',
              branches                         : [[name: gitBranch]],
              doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
              extensions                       : [],
              submoduleCfg                     : [],
              userRemoteConfigs                : [[credentialsId: gitCredentials, url: gitBORepo]]])
    sh 'git submodule init && git submodule update --remote'

  }

  stage('wiki_gradle') {
    rtGradle.tool = "gradle2.5"
    def gradleTask = 'cleanComplete'

    buildInfo = rtGradle.run rootDir: 'bo/delivery', buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: gradleTask
  }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.Utils$1.invoke(Utils.java:140)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.Utils$1.invoke(Utils.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.Utils.extractVcsRevision(Utils.java:136)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.Utils.extractVcsRevision(Utils.java:144)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.ArtifactoryGradleBuild$Execution.run(ArtifactoryGradleBuild.java:111)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.ArtifactoryGradleBuild$Execution.run(ArtifactoryGradleBuild.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried to fix it using dir(bo), env.WORKSPACE = env.WORKSPACE + '/ bo', but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share a bit more on where the error occurred? Is there any additional information in the Jenkins output? Also, can you check if the folder `bo/delivery` exists after running the scripts?

Comment: Which version of the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin is installed in your Jenkins?